# GWT Exporter - How do i create an instance of object at runtime. Object type will be available as a string argument

Tags: gwt, jsni

I am using the following code in GWT client 
Inside my jsni method I am using the following code, Assume that typeName is String argument

```
typeName = '$wnd.mysample.SampleButton'
var sample = new window[typeName]();
sample.addButton(name, parent);
```

SampleButton implements Exportable class, I used `@ExportPackage("mysample")` and `@Export(all = true)`.
    In My entry module I called `ExporterUtil.exportAll();`

Note: if I replace  
 
`var sample = new $wnd.mysample.SampleButton() with new window[typeName]()`     
 then it is working fine otherwise it is throwing undefined function called.
  Kindly let me know how to create an instance for the type in JSNI code

Answer (score 0):

eval('var sample = $wnd.mysample.SampleButton();'); solves the issue.